# MVC 3: How can I validate partial views on a page and issue one Post?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm adding 2 partial views, each with its own Form into a container view. The partial views have their own cotrollers. The container view has its own Form, too, but I'm not nesting Forms.

```
@Html.Action("Create", "RequestorInformation")
@Html.Action("Create", "UserInformation")
```

The Form for the RequestorInformation partial view looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "RequestorInformation", new { id = "formRequestorInformation" })) { 
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

The Form for the UserInformation partial view looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "UserInformation", new { id = "formUserInformation" })) { 
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

The Form for the container view looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "SSAR", new { id = "formSSAR" })) {
```

To validate and save all the data on the page I run this **script A** (thanks to Milimetric
):

```
    $('form').each(function (formIndex, formElement) {
        var f = $(formElement);
        alert('formIndex: ' + formIndex);
        if ($(this).validate()) {
            $.post(f.attr('action'), f.serialize(), successfulFormPost)
        }
    });
```

The script recurses through each Form, which if valid, Posts to the appropriate method on a controller. The Posts for the partial views are executed and ModelState is evaluated, but there are no data operations.

My issue is this: I need to 'manually' validate each partial view and then make one Post for the container Form that will perform data operations as needed.

I've tried to do the following with this **script B**:

```
$("#SubmitForm").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('formRequestorInformation').validate();
    if ($('formRequestorInformation').valid()) {
        alert('Requestor Form Is Valid!!');
    }
});
```

But I get the following error in jQuery Validation Plugin 1.8.0.:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'this.0.form' is null or not an object
```

Question: How can I individually validate the partial views on the page and when all are valid, make one Post?

Thanks,

Arnold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that the libraries I was using were not in sync. I started over from scratch after reinstalling and repairing and now things work as advertised.

I'm using user controls w/o forms added into a main Form like this:

```
@Html.Action("Action", "Controller")
```

A simple submit button validates the whole Form

Repaired Telerik: Telerik_Extensions_for_ASPNET_MVC_2011_1_315_OpenSource

Thanks,

Arnold